# Visual Studio won't reckognise KeyCode

Tags: unity-game-engine, keycode

I am using Unity and started working on a 2D guitar hero type game, the problem I am having is in my declarations after MonoBehaviour I wrote

{
public KeyCode key;

etc
}

the problem is Visual studio does not seem to reckognise KeyCode and I don't know why.

NOTE: in the systems I already have:

System.Collections;
using Unity engine;
Using Unity

Comment: It's an enumeration from `UnityEngine` namespace. What you have listed here for using is "using Unity engine". Note the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Import the `UnityEngine` namespace to use the `KeyCode` enumeration

You are currently importing the wrong class: "using Unity engine". You need to import with "using UnityEngine;"